# Upgrade solution package exported from CRM 2011 so it can be imported in CRM 2015

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm, microsoft-dynamics

While upgrading a solution from CRM 2011 to CRM 2015, I only changed the header of solution.xml file generated in crm 2011 solution export zip to

```
<ImportExportXml version="7.0.0000.4013" SolutionPackageVersion="7.0" languagecode="1033" 
generatedBy="CrmLive" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

and then I imported it to crm 2015. It got imported successfully.

Have any of you found any other way to import to crm 2015 from crm 2011 ?

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it will not be possible to import your solution this way, due to breaking changes in the solution file. In those cases you could follow these steps:

1. Import your solution in a clean CRM 2011 organization.
2. (If needed) upgrade your CRM deployment to the most recent rollup update for CRM 2011.
3. Upgrade your deployment to CRM 2013.
4. Upgrade your CRM deployment to the most recent rollup update for CRM 2013.
5. Upgrade your deployment to CRM 2015.
6. Export your solution.
7. Import your solution in your target CRM 2015 organization.

If the solution import does not complain about the validity of your solution, you should be safe to proceed. The import does its checks on the customization xml, so it can not damage your target organization.

Comment: CRM 2011 solutions can be imported into CRM 2013 environments, so you could skip a few of these steps.  Also, if the OP has a managed solution, this provides little value as the OP couldn't get it out of this other 2015 environment.